# Is it possible to get the SQL Server built-in function definition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get the definition of built in functions in SQL Server like MAX(), FORMAT() & others ?

Dint found any answers telling how to get the definition of these...

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for underlying code or just a definition? If it is definition you will get it in msdn rite?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, please share with me the msdn link having the definition of max function ...

Comment: Why that is the problem?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Before voting close, please specify the reason. I would appreciate if you could share with me the duplicate link of answer for my question.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, where is the underlying definition of Format function in the provided link. Please specify.

Comment: What you mean by definition? the whole code?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the definition? SQL Server is a proprietary, closed-source software product; its source code isn't publicly available. The documentation details its behaviour. So what you are actually asking?

Comment: @AakashM, Yes, I am asking for the SQL code - CREATE FUNCTION of the built in function & not the MS software. Like how we get the definition of most of system stored procedures. Please refer answer below by TheGameiswar, which was expected. thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get code for built in functions like `getdate(),max(),min()`,to see how they  are implemented.Say for example

```
sp_helptext 'getdate()'--won't yield any thing
```

But you can get defintion for most of system stored procedures say for example..

```
sp_helptext 'internal.cleanup_Server_retention_window'
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar. I understand the built in function definitions are not available.